# Git pull --rebase converting spaces to tabs

Tags: git, tabs, rebase, spaces, pull

This problem is driving me mad. Using Git with Github.

I'm working on one particular file using spaces instead of tabs. I always ensure that I change all tab indents to spaces. Diffs confirm that I've changed tabs to spaces. I commit and push the code (with other changes) and all is good.

Until, I `git pull --rebase`. Now, my file -- in parts -- has tabs replacing spaces! Note, this is on parts of the file that only I have ever edited and I always use spaces, not tabs.

It doesn't happen when I do a normal `git pull`, only on rebase.

Additionally, changes on other branches that are merged into the main integration branch are also OK. It's just happens on rebase of the integration branch.

Comment: Are there any Hooks registerd? Or something configured in your $home/.gitconfig? There are option that can be set like whitespace=fix or something like this. You should watch out for this. Search for core.whiteapce in  http://www.progit.org/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: Yeah, no hooks. It's probably something with my IDE. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Eclipse an EGit. Checkout the eclipse setting for EGit. It is possible to set the settings in there ;)

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well, and I'm using vim as my editor, and pulling from the command line.

Comment: Check in your .git/info/attributes file. See if you have any settings in there that might effect that file. git attributes are often used for manipulating files after commit/before save and after checkout/before opening. http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html

Comment: For me it was the line `whitespace = fix` in my `~/.gitconfig` file. I commented that out and was good to go. That's what I get for copying and pasting dot files.

Answer (score 7):

```
git apply --whitespace=fix
```

appears to make that happen during rebase.

Maybe set

```
[apply]
    whitespace = warn
```

in your gitconfig and see if it resolves your issue.

See also the ["core.whitespace" setting](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#idp16977232) for more.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by line endings settings. You can configure your git using instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).